# duplicate value for composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table friend : 
[image]

when I want to insert two new records like (1,2, true), (1,2, false) I got duplicate du champ '1-2' its logic,  because when I insert another Two records (1,2, true) (2,1, false) it goes well.  my question is why? I think that (1,2) (2,1) is also duplicated for the composite primary key (request_to  , request_from )

my sql queries :

```
INSERT INTO `friends` (`request_to`, `request_from`, `confirmed`, `date_confirmation`) VALUES ('11', '12', b'1', NULL), ('12', '11', '', NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a primary key on `request_to` and `request_from`.

That means that you cannot insert duplicate values into this column.  In your example that fails, `(1, 2)` is duplicated.  In your example that works, `(1, 2) <> (2, 1)`, so it is okay (for this constraint).

If you want uniqueness regardless of direction, add a unique constraint:

```
create unique index unq_friends_to_from on
    friends(least(request_to, request_from), greatest(request_to, request_from));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i prevent  duplication like this (1,2) (2,1) for my composite primary key ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like the PRIMARY key "request_to" is enough to create a constraint violation for the duplicate (1) .

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i prevent duplication like this (1,2) (2,1) for my composite primary key ?